# Where can I find the list of [[ ]] options?

Tags: test

like

```
[[ -s file ]]
[[ -z string ]]
```

preferably on the web.

I looked on the ldp site but couldn't find them

The man page (`man [`) is helpful but I am looking for a more compact list.

Comment: Like these - http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html ?

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify the shell you're using, but e.g.

```
man bash 
/CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS
```

Comment: Or for a web based version of the man page - http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of the `bash` builtin file and string test operators by typing `help test` at the shell prompt.

Answer (score 0):

```
man test | sed -n '/^  *-/,/^$/{/./p}'
```

tends to compact it a little bit